# What does it mean when an optional variable is <uninitialized> in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller that shows detail for my "SkillGroup" entity. I want to use this for both viewing and editing/creating a "SkillGroup". Thus I have an optional variable skillGroup which is either unset - and nil when you are first creating the SkillGroup and before you save it, OR it is set and you will be simply viewing the SkillGroup. Here is my code

```
class GroupViewController:UIViewController { 
    
    var skillGroup: SkillGroup?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let skillGroup = skillGroup {
            self.title = skillGroup.name
        }
    }
}
```

and in the previous view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "createGroupSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as? GroupViewController
        destination?.createOrEdit = true
    }
    if segue.identifier == "showGroupSegue" {
        if let selectedGroupPath = self.groupsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destination = segue.destination as? GroupViewController
            destination?.createOrEdit = false
            let group = groups[selectedGroupPath.row]
            destination?.skillGroup = group
        }
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint right after the call to super, and I inspect skillGroup, it says its `<uninitialized>`. I don't think this because its "nil" like a normal optional variable that hasn't been set. Additionally I did set the skillGroup variable in the prepare for segue code.

I really can't find much information on what  means. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, ah sorry. I guess the <> brackets somehow omit the entry. I added quotes so you can see it now

Comment: Maybe you're breakpointing for another instance ie one that doesn't come from the `prepare(for` method. I suggest you put a breakpoint at `destination?.skillGroup = group` , make sure `group` isn't `nil`, but also while you've hit the breakpoint there, set a breakpoint onto your `if let skillGroup = skillGroup ` and see what happens.

Comment: If I try this with a `String?` then it is `nil` right after `super.viewDidLoad()`. Maybe you are inspecting the wrong variable (the one that only lives in the `if let ...` scope)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are inspecting the wrong variable in the debugger (the local variable instead of the instance variable).

I made a quick sample:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  public class TestClass {
    var foo: String
    var bar: Int
    
    init() {
      foo = "foo"
      bar = 4711
    }
  }
  
  public var test: TestClass?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    test = TestClass()
    
    if let test = test {
      print(test.foo)
    }
  }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the line `if let test = test {` I will see the following in the debugger:

[image: debugger]

Here you can see that it will print `<uninitialized>` when I print the description of the local `test` variable because the `let` statement on that line was not executed yet.

Please note that there is a local variable (only living inside the `if` scope) and an instance variable. In the debugger you will see the instance variables when you expand the `self` node.